# Subscribe to Kafka Topics over websocket from client side

Tags: javascript, websocket, apache-kafka, stomp, sockjs

We are trying to listen to the kafka topics using js code from browser once the Producer from server side pushes messages to the particular kafka topic.

In the server side, kafka server and zookeeper are running at 9092 and 2181 port respectively.

```
String topicName = "test"; 
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");     
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 0);
props.put("batch.size", 16384);
props.put("linger.ms", 1);
props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
props.put("key.serializer", 
     "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", 
             "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("partitioner.class",
        "org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner");
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer <String, String>(props);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topicName, 
       Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i) + i));
    }
producer.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Client code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>My Page</head>
<script src="stomp.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.sockjs.org/sockjs-0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log('Starting: ');
var socket = new SockJS('ws://localhost:9092');
client = Stomp.over(socket);
client.connect( "", "",
        function() {
            console.log('Connected: ');
            client.subscribe("/topic/test",
                function( message ) {
                    alert( message );
                }  
            );
        }
);
</script>
</html>
```

From client side, while we are trying to connect via ws, only the Starting: console is getting printed and Connected: is not getting rpinted since the 
websocket connection to the kafka server is not getting succeeded.

Since STOMP is not directly supported for Kafka, we tried to sue SockJS.

Can anyone please help us out to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Why is it that you want to connect directly to Kafka, and not from a server? For example, it is very easy to connect from a Node.js server to subscribe to Kafka, and then have your websocket connection only between the client app and the Node service that passes through any new events from Kafka.

Comment: Also, here is an example of somebody who seems to have figured it out: https://github.com/abhirockzz/kafka-websocket/blob/master/dashboard/src/main/webapp/index.html   They use the "new Websocket" API on the client to make the connection.

Comment: Not sure if you found answer to your question but I am curious to know how did you managed to secure Kafka from unwanted clients?

Comment: For what it is worth at this late stage, here is a Spring project that supports STOMP protocol. https://dzone.com/articles/live-dashboard-using-apache-kafka-and-spring-webso
In brief though, you need some way to translate the Kafka push into a websocket/SSE push.